# libavcodec-dev package missing

Tags: apt, 16.04, live-usb

I am trying to compile MakeMKV for a persistent Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB. One of the dependencies is libavcodec-dev, but whenever I try to install it I am told the package is not found. I search on google and find pages like [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libavcodec-dev) which suggest that it should be there. What's going on? Is it because it is a Live USB? Is the package repo limited? I have run `sudo apt-get update` to be sure and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you [enable the universe repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)?

Comment: @steeldriver Seems to have worked, thanks! I didn't realise I had to enable it. It was always enabled already when I've been using Ubuntu in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That package is available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu in the Universe repository when in doubt use [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libavcodec-dev) to not only verify a packages existence but also determine which repository it is in. Here's an example:

[image: libavcodec]